# bootstrap doesn't work, in my electron application

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, electron

hello i'm trying to make an application with electron and integrate bootstrap. when i tried the navbar (copy and paste from doc) it didn't display well.

[app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4U9O.png)

after whatever search, I checked my imports but everything looks normal to me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script scr="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <body>
        <h1>Bonjour le monde !</h1>
        Nous utilisons Node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
        Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
        et Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.

        <button id="btn">button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-success">Basic</button>

        <script>
            require('./renderer')
            window.$ = window.jquery = require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js') // I also tried with only require('jquery')
            require('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Bootstrap 4 Plugin and using Bootstrap 3 HTML.

Validating your HTML with Bootstrap 4, renders the same output as per your screenshot
https://www.codeply.com/go/6c6qWGrIpF/bootstrap-4-test-page
You can paste your HTML on the link above.

Changing the HTML as per Bootstrap 4 Navbar fixes the issue
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But I'm not sure I understood why, I'm just getting started.

Comment: Its simple, the styling is written in CSS and the functionality in a JS file. The output of an HTML in browser depends upon these two files. 

In your scenario the HTML which was used was of Bootstrap 3 version which required Bootstrap CSS and JS for BS-3. But CSS and JS present in your node_modules is of BS-4